# SSAS: distribution of measures over percentage

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, cube

I am running a SSAS cube that stores facts of HTTP requests. The is a column "Time Taken" that stores the milliseconds a particular HTTP request took.

Like...

```
RequestID     Time Taken
--------------------------
1             0
2             10
3             20
4             20
5             2000
```

I want to provide a report through Excel that shows the distribution of those timings by percentage of requests. A statement like "90% of all requests took less than 20millisecond".

Analysis:

```
100%          <2000
80%           <20
60%           <20
40%           <10
20%           <=0
```

I am pretty much lost what would be the right approach to design aggregations, calculations etc. to offer this analysis through Excel.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Providing a report "through" Excel is a bit ambiguous as Excel manages it's own data and does it's own calculations.  For data-manipulation and report-generation I far prefer Excel to SQL Server, which is after all truly an end-user product whereas SQL Server is more for management of data-stores.

Could you clarify whether your intention is to:

- manipulate the data in SQL Server into data for reports and then send that data to Excel, or...
- send the data to Excel so that it can then be manipulated into generated reports

Comment: "Providing a report "through" Excel is a bit ambiguous", I mean by that to use MS Excel as the BI client for a cube stored by SQL Server Analaysis Services. Does that already clarify your questions?